# Sent Variable to Controller via Ajax in Blade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have a variable contains this data below

```
{"_method":"PUT","_token":"rs8iLxwoJHSCj3Cc47jaP5gp8pO5lhGghF1WeDJQ","id":"1"}
```

---

I want to sent it to controller via Ajax

**I've tried**

```
$( "form#edit" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

    $("#edit :input").each(function() {
        inputs[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });

    var $inputs = JSON.stringify(inputs);

    $.ajax({
        url: $url,
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $inputs ,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            console.log('PUT error.', xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });

});
```

---

It kept failing on me. 
Did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: What do you get with `Input::all()` and `Input::json()` in your controller ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this: {"_method":"PUT", with an underscore, the underscore i sonly needed for the _token

Comment: @ihue and @Franco, I think this `"_method":"PUT"` has no impact here ;)

Comment: I didn't say that, I only sad that normally Laravel  requires the underscore for the token. I am still looking at the code, but I use an other method for sending data with 'ajax' in 'Laravel'. Any reason why he can not just serialize the form inputs from the form?

Comment: `_method` hidden input is a classic HTML hack for using PUT or DELETE HTTP request.

Comment: Can you please try to change the type from 'PUT' to 'POST'?

Comment: @ihue are you using the Form::model(...) facade to construct your form in your blade? Would be nice to know from where you are getting the $input json from.

Comment: In fact you will use Form::open() when you are posting a new record and Form::model(...)  when you are updating a new one. Because the standard HTML form methods are 'POST' and 'GET', the Form::model() fakes the non standard method 'PUT'.

Comment: @ihue : if the code at the beginning of your controller is never executed, your request should be stuck in a middleware. You have to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your jQuery code is over complicated. Something just like that should work :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: $url,
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function () {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

The jQuery function `serialize()` is the key here.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I am already sad! And I am still wondering from where the $input json is coming from.

Comment: `$("form").serialize()` is enough. It is made for this use case :)